# Enabling Form Button via Java Not Working on Mobile

Tags: java, jquery, html, safari

I have this script that will enable the submit button once one of the four checkboxes is selected. This script works successfully in chrome on a PC but not on an iPad device using safari. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <!---JQuery Iniialization --->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!--- This script disables submit button until check box is checked.--->
<script>
window.onload = function() {

    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
        submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

    checkboxes.click(function() {
        submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
    });
}
</script>
```

Here is my form

```
<form action="signature_action.cfm?ticketID=#url.ticketID#&TT=#url.TT#&techID=#url.techID#&device=ipad" method="post" NAME="SigForm" id="SigForm">

<input name="equipment_dropped_off" type="checkbox" id="check1" value="equipment_dropped_off" />
                                <label for="check1"><span class="style1">Equipment Dropped Off &nbsp; &nbsp; </span></label>
                                <span class="style1">
                                <input name="work" type="checkbox" id="check2" value="work"/>
                                <label for="check2">Work performed &nbsp; &nbsp; </label>
                                <input name="payment" id="check3" type="checkbox" value="payment" />
                                <label for="check3">Payment Recieved &nbsp; &nbsp; </label>
                                <input name="equipment_picked_up" id="check4" type="checkbox" value="equipment_picked_up" />
                                <label for="check4">Equipment Picked Up</label>

                                <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class='btn-style-mobile' value="Click Here To Accept Signature" disabled>

</form>
```

Comment: Simplest thing to try is to observe the "change" event instead of "click".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("#submit");

  function allChecked() {
    var result = true;
    checkboxes.each(function() {
        if(!$(this).is(":checked")) {
           result = false; 
        }  
    });
    return result;
  }

  checkboxes.on('change', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!allChecked()) {
        submitButt.attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
        submitButt.removeAttr('disabled');       
    }
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hb7f4k2r/

```
 //If you need this functionality for only one check-box. 
 //Add a specific class/id to that particular check-box.
 $(".specific-checkbox").on('change', function () {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      submitButt.removeAttr('disabled');
   } else {
       submitButt.attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
});
```

Comment: On my mobile device, this code doesn't seem to work. Nothing in my console. I added a Console.log as well  to the code that doesn't show in the log either. It's as if the code never fires. Do I need to specify a mobile jquery library or something. I'll update my post with the library that I am currently declaring.

Comment: Also, do I need to call the function allChecked() with an onclick?

Comment: Ok, so I moved my JS block below my form and not it is functioning properly. I guess my form was defined yet???? Not sure, I'm still a little blurry on most of this JS. But how would I adjust the code so that only one check box would need to be check instead of all?

Comment: Updated comments to correct typos: Ok, so I moved my javascript code block below my form and now it is functioning properly. I guess my form was not defined yet???? Not sure, I'm still a little blurry on most of this JS. But how would I adjust the code so that only one check box would need to be check instead of all?

Comment: The best practice is to have all js logic in JavaScript files and include them right before the closing body tag. I edited my answer and added the functionality for a particular check-box.

Comment: ok thanks. That makes sense. So your code that you added for a particular checkbox would replace function allChecked()?

Comment: It doesn't use that function. You can remove it if you are not using it elsewhere. Could you please mark my answer as the correct one, if you believe so (green check image). Thanks!

Comment: Certainly. When I test the new code, it is not recognizing the checked state. I put console.log() after each if clause and when I check and uncheck the box, it always runs the else part of the statement.

Comment: I found the error. I had to add a colon here: if ($(this).is(':checked'))